TIKTOK Content Posting API is not working with more than 1 chunk - Using the FILE_UPLOAD source
I am using the TIKTOK Content Posting API to upload the video to TIKTOK. It is working fine for the videos less than 64MB size but when the video is more than 64MB then it is showing the error on the server.
My node js code is as follows
await downloadFile(videoURL, tempDownloadPath);
const videoStats = fs.statSync(tempDownloadPath);
const videoSize = videoStats.size;

const MIN_CHUNK_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5 MB
const MAX_CHUNK_SIZE = 64 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB - Change this back to 64

let chunkSize = Math.min(MAX_CHUNK_SIZE, videoSize);
if (videoSize < MIN_CHUNK_SIZE) {
  chunkSize = videoSize;
}

const totalChunkCount = Math.ceil(videoSize / chunkSize);

let data = {
  post_info: {
    title: tiktokvideoTitle,
    privacy_level: tiktokaccessSpecifier,
    disable_duet: false,
    disable_comment: false,
    disable_stitch: false,
    video_cover_timestamp_ms: 1000,
    brand_content_toggle: false,
    brand_organic_toggle: false
  },
  source_info: {
    source: "FILE_UPLOAD",
    video_size: videoSize,
    chunk_size: chunkSize,
    total_chunk_count: totalChunkCount
  }
};

console.log("data =====", data);

const initResponse = await axios.post('https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/video/init/', data, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
  }
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('Error initializing video upload:', err);
  throw new Error('Failed to initialize video upload');
});

I am getting the following error on server
0|socialUploader  | Error initializing video upload: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400
0|socialUploader  |     at settle (/home/socialuploader-backend/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:1967:12)
0|socialUploader  |     at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/ssemble/socialuploader-backend/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:3062:11)
0|socialUploader  |     at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:531:35)
0|socialUploader  |     at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
0|socialUploader  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
0|socialUploader  |   code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
0|socialUploader  |   config: {
0|socialUploader  |     transitional: {
0|socialUploader  |       silentJSONParsing: true,
0|socialUploader  |       forcedJSONParsing: true,
0|socialUploader  |       clarifyTimeoutError: false
0|socialUploader  |     },
0|socialUploader  |     adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
0|socialUploader  |     transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
0|socialUploader  |     transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
0|socialUploader  |     timeout: 0,
0|socialUploader  |     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
0|socialUploader  |     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
0|socialUploader  |     maxContentLength: -1,
0|socialUploader  |     maxBodyLength: -1,
0|socialUploader  |     env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
0|socialUploader  |     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
0|socialUploader  |     headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
0|socialUploader  |       Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
0|socialUploader  |       'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
0|socialUploader  |       Authorization: 'Bearer act.whzQnXJIBlaAoNXinygTmE4N7iJWu7uYNAvh8TfXxJqAdqETHJ3snkJexaeT!5654.e1',
0|socialUploader  |       'User-Agent': 'axios/1.6.3',
0|socialUploader  |       'Content-Length': '476',
0|socialUploader  |       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
0|socialUploader  |     },
0|socialUploader  |     method: 'post',
0|socialUploader  |     url: 'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/video/init/',
0|socialUploader  |     data: `{"post_info":{"title":"Unravel the 'nice guy' myth. Discover the truth behind being genuine and attractive without getting walked over. #NiceGuys #DatingAdvice #SelfRespect","privacy_level":"PUBLIC_TO_EVERYONE","disable_duet":false,"disable_comment":false,"disable_stitch":false,"video_cover_timestamp_ms":1000,"brand_content_toggle":false,"brand_organic_toggle":false},"source_info":{"source":"FILE_UPLOAD","video_size":103107045,"chunk_size":67108864,"total_chunk_count":2}}`
0|socialUploader  |   },
0|socialUploader  |   request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
0|socialUploader  |     _events: [Object: null prototype] {
0|socialUploader  |       abort: [Function (anonymous)],
0|socialUploader  |       aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
0|socialUploader  |       connect: [Function (anonymous)],
0|socialUploader  |       error: [Function (anonymous)],
0|socialUploader  |       socket: [Function (anonymous)],
0|socialUploader  |       timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
0|socialUploader  |       finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
0|socialUploader  |     },
0|socialUploader  |     _eventsCount: 7,
0|socialUploader  |     _maxListeners: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |     outputData: [],
0|socialUploader  |     outputSize: 0,
0|socialUploader  |     writable: true,
0|socialUploader  |     destroyed: false,
0|socialUploader  |     _last: false,
0|socialUploader  |     chunkedEncoding: false,
0|socialUploader  |     shouldKeepAlive: false,
0|socialUploader  |     maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
0|socialUploader  |     _defaultKeepAlive: true,
0|socialUploader  |     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
0|socialUploader  |     sendDate: false,
0|socialUploader  |     _removedConnection: false,
0|socialUploader  |     _removedContLen: false,
0|socialUploader  |     _removedTE: false,
0|socialUploader  |     strictContentLength: false,
0|socialUploader  |     _contentLength: '476',
0|socialUploader  |     _hasBody: true,
0|socialUploader  |     _trailer: '',
0|socialUploader  |     finished: true,
0|socialUploader  |     _headerSent: true,
0|socialUploader  |     _closed: false,
0|socialUploader  |     socket: TLSSocket {
0|socialUploader  |       _tlsOptions: [Object],
0|socialUploader  |       _secureEstablished: true,
0|socialUploader  |       _securePending: false,
0|socialUploader  |       _newSessionPending: false,
0|socialUploader  |       _controlReleased: true,
0|socialUploader  |       secureConnecting: false,
0|socialUploader  |       _SNICallback: null,
0|socialUploader  |       servername: 'open.tiktokapis.com',
0|socialUploader  |       alpnProtocol: false,
0|socialUploader  |       authorized: true,
0|socialUploader  |       authorizationError: null,
0|socialUploader  |       encrypted: true,
0|socialUploader  |       _events: [Object: null prototype],
0|socialUploader  |       _eventsCount: 10,
0|socialUploader  |       connecting: false,
0|socialUploader  |       _hadError: false,
0|socialUploader  |       _parent: null,
0|socialUploader  |       _host: 'open.tiktokapis.com',
0|socialUploader  |       _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
0|socialUploader  |       _readableState: [ReadableState],
0|socialUploader  |       _writableState: [WritableState],
0|socialUploader  |       allowHalfOpen: false,
0|socialUploader  |       _maxListeners: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |       _sockname: null,
0|socialUploader  |       _pendingData: null,
0|socialUploader  |       _pendingEncoding: '',
0|socialUploader  |       server: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |       _server: null,
0|socialUploader  |       ssl: [TLSWrap],
0|socialUploader  |       _requestCert: true,
0|socialUploader  |       _rejectUnauthorized: true,
0|socialUploader  |       timeout: 5000,
0|socialUploader  |       parser: null,
0|socialUploader  |       _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
0|socialUploader  |       autoSelectFamilyAttemptedAddresses: [Array],
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(alpncallback)]: null,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(verified)]: true,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 22235383,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
0|socialUploader  |         _idleTimeout: 5000,
0|socialUploader  |         _idlePrev: [TimersList],
0|socialUploader  |         _idleNext: [Timeout],
0|socialUploader  |         _idleStart: 178692186,
0|socialUploader  |         _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
0|socialUploader  |         _timerArgs: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |         _repeat: null,
0|socialUploader  |         _destroyed: false,
0|socialUploader  |         [Symbol(refed)]: false,
0|socialUploader  |         [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
0|socialUploader  |         [Symbol(asyncId)]: 22186526,
0|socialUploader  |         [Symbol(triggerId)]: 22186524
0|socialUploader  |       },
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
0|socialUploader  |     },
0|socialUploader  |     _header: 'POST /v2/post/publish/video/init/ HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |       'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |       'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |       'Authorization: Bearer act.whzQnXJIBlaAoNXinygTmE4N7iJWu7uYNAvh8TfXxJqAdqETHJ3snkJexaeT!5654.e1\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |       'User-Agent: axios/1.6.3\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |       'Content-Length: 476\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |       'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |       'Host: open.tiktokapis.com\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |       'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |       '\r\n',
0|socialUploader  |     _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
0|socialUploader  |     _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
0|socialUploader  |     agent: Agent {
0|socialUploader  |       _events: [Object: null prototype],
0|socialUploader  |       _eventsCount: 2,
0|socialUploader  |       _maxListeners: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |       defaultPort: 443,
0|socialUploader  |       protocol: 'https:',
0|socialUploader  |       options: [Object: null prototype],
0|socialUploader  |       requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
0|socialUploader  |       sockets: [Object: null prototype],
0|socialUploader  |       freeSockets: [Object: null prototype],
0|socialUploader  |       keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
0|socialUploader  |       keepAlive: true,
0|socialUploader  |       maxSockets: Infinity,
0|socialUploader  |       maxFreeSockets: 256,
0|socialUploader  |       scheduling: 'lifo',
0|socialUploader  |       maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
0|socialUploader  |       totalSocketCount: 2,
0|socialUploader  |       maxCachedSessions: 100,
0|socialUploader  |       _sessionCache: [Object],
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
0|socialUploader  |     },
0|socialUploader  |     socketPath: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |     method: 'POST',
0|socialUploader  |     maxHeaderSize: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |     insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |     joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |     path: '/v2/post/publish/video/init/',
0|socialUploader  |     _ended: true,
0|socialUploader  |     res: IncomingMessage {
0|socialUploader  |       _events: [Object],
0|socialUploader  |       _readableState: [ReadableState],
0|socialUploader  |       _maxListeners: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |       socket: [TLSSocket],
0|socialUploader  |       httpVersionMajor: 1,
0|socialUploader  |       httpVersionMinor: 1,
0|socialUploader  |       httpVersion: '1.1',
0|socialUploader  |       complete: true,
0|socialUploader  |       rawHeaders: [Array],
0|socialUploader  |       rawTrailers: [],
0|socialUploader  |       joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |       aborted: false,
0|socialUploader  |       upgrade: false,
0|socialUploader  |       url: '',
0|socialUploader  |       method: null,
0|socialUploader  |       statusCode: 400,
0|socialUploader  |       statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
0|socialUploader  |       client: [TLSSocket],
0|socialUploader  |       _consuming: true,
0|socialUploader  |       _dumped: false,
0|socialUploader  |       req: [Circular *1],
0|socialUploader  |       _eventsCount: 4,
0|socialUploader  |       responseUrl: 'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/video/init/',
0|socialUploader  |       redirects: [],
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 34,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
0|socialUploader  |     },
0|socialUploader  |     aborted: false,
0|socialUploader  |     timeoutCb: [Function: emitRequestTimeout],
0|socialUploader  |     upgradeOrConnect: false,
0|socialUploader  |     parser: null,
0|socialUploader  |     maxHeadersCount: null,
0|socialUploader  |     reusedSocket: true,
0|socialUploader  |     host: 'open.tiktokapis.com',
0|socialUploader  |     protocol: 'https:',
0|socialUploader  |     _redirectable: Writable {
0|socialUploader  |       _events: [Object],
0|socialUploader  |       _writableState: [WritableState],
0|socialUploader  |       _maxListeners: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |       _options: [Object],
0|socialUploader  |       _ended: true,
0|socialUploader  |       _ending: true,
0|socialUploader  |       _redirectCount: 0,
0|socialUploader  |       _redirects: [],
0|socialUploader  |       _requestBodyLength: 476,
0|socialUploader  |       _requestBodyBuffers: [],
0|socialUploader  |       _eventsCount: 3,
0|socialUploader  |       _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
0|socialUploader  |       _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
0|socialUploader  |       _currentUrl: 'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/video/init/',
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
0|socialUploader  |     },
0|socialUploader  |     [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
0|socialUploader  |     [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
0|socialUploader  |     [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
0|socialUploader  |     [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
0|socialUploader  |     [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
0|socialUploader  |     [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
0|socialUploader  |       accept: [Array],
0|socialUploader  |       'content-type': [Array],
0|socialUploader  |       authorization: [Array],
0|socialUploader  |       'user-agent': [Array],
0|socialUploader  |       'content-length': [Array],
0|socialUploader  |       'accept-encoding': [Array],
0|socialUploader  |       host: [Array]
0|socialUploader  |     },
0|socialUploader  |     [Symbol(errored)]: null,
0|socialUploader  |     [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
0|socialUploader  |     [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
0|socialUploader  |     [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
0|socialUploader  |   },
0|socialUploader  |   response: {
0|socialUploader  |     status: 400,
0|socialUploader  |     statusText: 'Bad Request',
0|socialUploader  |     headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
0|socialUploader  |       'content-type': 'application/json',
0|socialUploader  |       'content-length': '126',
0|socialUploader  |       'x-janus-info': 'GucksBLCW4ga4RTrAOipfSoEdGQ1f7CQPxXfwQDUQv-0PUVpHehBMf2BH74VA4s6BTJdebptPkQR2ls_-3d9JpWbmmzrbRIzGIrzGG4M9MIJLjt-iuNsuELzR7Z-cIXvu-LrM5h0ad82o44VXc8u51rLkOtkS2LodveVOTzPT0QdrlgSql640NVuVzPnCGjDDTlVt2fg5MTdielv1zjvcmp8uPHdUdaKOriRiLWw_znrd8MawIJX9FC86CC-RFM_4i-gvpg2esp02TSaB5vlXg==',
0|socialUploader  |       'x-tt-logid': '2024101905500118C64F950EF28F73F53F',
0|socialUploader  |       'x-tt-trace-host': '01eb53e39bc3f3bdb889d4ae199ecc6b05080c020ef3bdd5527279803072ef22810f076faa993027f108408d003f84ba12407c7d4ee53347ca43df8174ee268193967b86e8e9ddab04a0df049b493cc2ce2abac446befa59126a3eb4110054e97fa31a5262ff3e5239ec051ada9b1ca8fb',
0|socialUploader  |       'x-tt-trace-id': '00-24101905500118C64F950EF28F73F53F-19D5CB8D2CF8EBC6-00',
0|socialUploader  |       server: 'TLB',
0|socialUploader  |       'x-origin-response-time': '43,104.78.78.101',
0|socialUploader  |       expires: 'Sat, 19 Oct 2024 05:50:02 GMT',
0|socialUploader  |       'cache-control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store',
0|socialUploader  |       pragma: 'no-cache',
0|socialUploader  |       date: 'Sat, 19 Oct 2024 05:50:02 GMT',
0|socialUploader  |       connection: 'close',
0|socialUploader  |       'x-tt-trace-tag': 'id=16;cdn-cache=miss;type=dyn',
0|socialUploader  |       'server-timing': 'cdn-cache; desc=MISS, edge; dur=30, origin; dur=43, inner; dur=38',
0|socialUploader  |       'x-parent-response-time': '67,23.220.105.205'
0|socialUploader  |     },
0|socialUploader  |     config: {
0|socialUploader  |       transitional: [Object],
0|socialUploader  |       adapter: [Array],
0|socialUploader  |       transformRequest: [Array],
0|socialUploader  |       transformResponse: [Array],
0|socialUploader  |       timeout: 0,
0|socialUploader  |       xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
0|socialUploader  |       xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
0|socialUploader  |       maxContentLength: -1,
0|socialUploader  |       maxBodyLength: -1,
0|socialUploader  |       env: [Object],
0|socialUploader  |       validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
0|socialUploader  |       headers: [Object [AxiosHeaders]],
0|socialUploader  |       method: 'post',
0|socialUploader  |       url: 'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/video/init/',
0|socialUploader  |       data: `{"post_info":{"title":"Unravel the 'nice guy' myth. Discover the truth behind being genuine and attractive without getting walked over. #NiceGuys #DatingAdvice #SelfRespect","privacy_level":"PUBLIC_TO_EVERYONE","disable_duet":false,"disable_comment":false,"disable_stitch":false,"video_cover_timestamp_ms":1000,"brand_content_toggle":false,"brand_organic_toggle":false},"source_info":{"source":"FILE_UPLOAD","video_size":103107045,"chunk_size":67108864,"total_chunk_count":2}}`
0|socialUploader  |     },
0|socialUploader  |     request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
0|socialUploader  |       _events: [Object: null prototype],
0|socialUploader  |       _eventsCount: 7,
0|socialUploader  |       _maxListeners: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |       outputData: [],
0|socialUploader  |       outputSize: 0,
0|socialUploader  |       writable: true,
0|socialUploader  |       destroyed: false,
0|socialUploader  |       _last: false,
0|socialUploader  |       chunkedEncoding: false,
0|socialUploader  |       shouldKeepAlive: false,
0|socialUploader  |       maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
0|socialUploader  |       _defaultKeepAlive: true,
0|socialUploader  |       useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
0|socialUploader  |       sendDate: false,
0|socialUploader  |       _removedConnection: false,
0|socialUploader  |       _removedContLen: false,
0|socialUploader  |       _removedTE: false,
0|socialUploader  |       strictContentLength: false,
0|socialUploader  |       _contentLength: '476',
0|socialUploader  |       _hasBody: true,
0|socialUploader  |       _trailer: '',
0|socialUploader  |       finished: true,
0|socialUploader  |       _headerSent: true,
0|socialUploader  |       _closed: false,
0|socialUploader  |       socket: [TLSSocket],
0|socialUploader  |       _header: 'POST /v2/post/publish/video/init/ HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |         'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |         'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |         'Authorization: Bearer act.whzQnXJIBlaAoNXinygTmE4N7iJWu7uYNAvh8TfXxJqAdqETHJ3snkJexaeT!5654.e1\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |         'User-Agent: axios/1.6.3\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |         'Content-Length: 476\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |         'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |         'Host: open.tiktokapis.com\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |         'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
0|socialUploader  |         '\r\n',
0|socialUploader  |       _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
0|socialUploader  |       _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
0|socialUploader  |       agent: [Agent],
0|socialUploader  |       socketPath: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |       method: 'POST',
0|socialUploader  |       maxHeaderSize: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |       insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |       joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
0|socialUploader  |       path: '/v2/post/publish/video/init/',
0|socialUploader  |       _ended: true,
0|socialUploader  |       res: [IncomingMessage],
0|socialUploader  |       aborted: false,
0|socialUploader  |       timeoutCb: [Function: emitRequestTimeout],
0|socialUploader  |       upgradeOrConnect: false,
0|socialUploader  |       parser: null,
0|socialUploader  |       maxHeadersCount: null,
0|socialUploader  |       reusedSocket: true,
0|socialUploader  |       host: 'open.tiktokapis.com',
0|socialUploader  |       protocol: 'https:',
0|socialUploader  |       _redirectable: [Writable],
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(errored)]: null,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
0|socialUploader  |       [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
0|socialUploader  |     },
0|socialUploader  |     data: { error: [Object] }
0|socialUploader  |   }
0|socialUploader  | }


If someone faced the problem and have solution.
Thanks
I tried different ways to generate the chunks but nothing worked for me.

data: { error: [Object] } - can you please inspect this property in detail, so that we can see what it actually contains?

@C3roe Further checking this object, it says
Error data: {
code: 'invalid_params',
message: 'The total chunk count is invalid',
log_id: '20241022011102912722DAF18D59F20DC7'
}
I tried both the math.ceil and math.floor but the error is same for both. It is happening only when the video is more than 64MB which is the max chunk size allowed by tiktok.

It has to be ceil. If your video is 51 MB in size, and your chunk size is 50 MB - then you want 2 as your total number of chunks, and not 1. What are the actual values you are sending, have you debugged that?
